# rails: datetimes fields do not fetch the values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written a code with acts_as_api for a dates_model. The code is as following. It never fetches the dates. Am I doing anything wrong. The code is as follows

```
    acts_as_api

    api_accessible :bill_corrections do |inv|
       inv.add :common_date, :as => :recieved_date, :if => lambda{|u|u.date_type_code=="RECVD"}
       inv.add :common_date, :as => :actual_date, :if => lambda{|u|u.date_type_code=="ARRIV"}
  end
```

I've my schema for datefield

```
create_table "item_dates", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_date_id",   :limit => 10
    t.string   "date_type_code"
    t.datetime "common_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: By "fetches" do you mean "load" or "return"? Have you checked that your conditional is really fulfilled? Have you tried to return another field to see if it returns anything?

Comment: @polarblau, I meant return. All other fields are getting returned except for dates api. What I pasted here is part of acts_as_api response. I've other around 11 models use the same acts_as_api response. They all get the response. Only api from dates does not fetch the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of acts_as_api. I tried your use case with a minimal Rails app and it worked for me. Here is an example response in xml:

```
<users type="array">
  <user>
    <first-name>Me</first-name>
    <recieved-date type="datetime">2011-10-07T08:20:02Z</recieved-date>
  </user>
  <user>
    <first-name>Me2</first-name>
    <actual-date type="datetime">2011-10-07T08:20:52Z</actual-date>
  </user>
</users>
```

The api template in the model looks like this:

```
api_accessible :test_dates do |t|
  t.add :first_name
  t.add :common_date, :as => :recieved_date, :if => lambda{|u|u.date_type_code=="RECVD"}
  t.add :common_date, :as => :actual_date, :if => lambda{|u|u.date_type_code=="ARRIV"}
end
```

And this is a dump of User.all:

```
[
    [0] #<User:0x0000010b859308> {
                    :id => 1,
            :first_name => "Me",
             :last_name => "Too",
                   :age => nil,
                :active => nil,
            :created_at => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:19 UTC +00:00,
            :updated_at => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:19 UTC +00:00,
        :date_type_code => "RECVD",
           :common_date => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:02 UTC +00:00
    },
    [1] #<User:0x0000010b858688> {
                    :id => 2,
            :first_name => "Me2",
             :last_name => "Too2",
                   :age => nil,
                :active => nil,
            :created_at => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:45 UTC +00:00,
            :updated_at => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:53 UTC +00:00,
        :date_type_code => "ARRIV",
           :common_date => Fri, 07 Oct 2011 08:20:52 UTC +00:00
    }
]
```

Did you check that you use the controller helpers correctly?

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render_for_api :test_dates, :xml => @users, :root => :users  }
    format.json { render_for_api :test_dates, :json => @users, :root => :users }
  end
end
```

I hope this helps. :)

Further debugging could include:
* What happens if you remove the :if options?
* What does 'puts u.date_type_code' say if you put it in the :if options blocks?

Comment: Thanks You Chris for looking into my question. I'm a newbie to rails, so don't know too many debugging options.Ill try this.

Comment: I verified, it is my model which does not fetch any datetime fields. What do I do? Is there any configurations that I need to control...!

Comment: I assume you use Rails 3 with ActiveRecord (and some kind of SQL DB)
What do you mean by "my model which does not fetch any datetime fields"?

Can you start up the rails console and type something like:

    ItemDate.first.attributes

Do you see your needed attributes there?

You also can have a look at the log, to make sure you always select all required fields (but SELECT * is default for Rails).

Comment: I get all attributes in the rails console, but any field which is datetime, its value is shown as nil. I use MS SQL Server.

Comment: I never used Rails with MS SQL Server, but if you always have nil values (and there are other values in the db itself), it is most likely not the fault of acts_as_api.

Remove acts_as_api completely and have another look at the console. :)

Comment: :). Yeah I understand now. I need to change my title, rails does not fetch datetime fields...! Thank you for sparing time on this question.

Comment: I think you have better chances if you provide a simplified example that's focussed on rails and ms sql server.

Comment: Hello Sorry, wasn't there on Saturday..! I figured out.It is configuration issue in en.yml file where date format needs to set. Someone who knows ruby is already working on it...! So my hands off the date issue now :). Thanks a lot for helping me resolve this issue...!

Comment: Hi there,  I've wrote acts_as_api like this for items                                                                  `acts_as_api
  
  api_accessible :invoices do |inv|
    inv.add :id, :as => :item_id
    inv.add :transaction_type_number
    inv.add :product_code
    inv.add :get_product_group, :as => :product_group_code` and get_product_group is not a model attribute but a method  which is as follows `def get_product_group
     product_group = Product.joins(:product_group).select('product_groups.*').where(" product_code = ? ", self.product_code)   
     return product_group[0]; 
  end`

Comment: the above solution worked earlier, but during integration it seems to be failing? Any ideas?